# What event is fired when node is invalid in treepanel in extjs

Tags: extjs, treepanel

When a node is dropped it goes to beforenodedrop event in TreePanel

But what happens when node is invalid ? it doesn't drop and so beforenodedrop event is not notified

What event is that????? Can somebody please tell me?????

Thanks alot in advance
Regards

Comment: There is not event???? Nobody knows what event is fired when a node is INVALID????????????? Please help somebody

Comment: Not sure that one gets thrown as default. You could create your own DropZone object and apply it to the tree to implement your own...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do some processing on a tree node after an invalide drop:

There is a method in Ext.tree.TreeDragZone, override that method :

```
Ext.override(Ext.tree.TreeDragZone, {

        afterRepair:function(){

                            // Code to be processed on node after an invalid drop
            this.dragging = false;
        },

        getRepairXY : function(e){
            return false;
        }    
});
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Regards